# karaf : software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load an HTTP implementation from any provider in the chain

Tags: maven, exception, amazon-s3, apache-karaf

I am using karaf and maven in my application. I am doing successful  aws sso login by running command  "aws sso login --profile <PROFILE_NAME> before running my application. then running mvn install and then karaf command to run karaf.
I am getting below exception while trying to access s3 bucket.The same is working in other people's machine. I am using java 17. and software.amazon.sdk version is 2.20.99.

software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load an HTTP implementation from any provider in the chain. You must declare a dependency on an appropriate HTTP implementation or pass in an SdkHttpClient explicitly to the client builder.]
22:40:45.143 INFO [DefaultQuartzScheduler-com.elsevier.dkp.batch-services-batchLoader_Worker-7] Job dkp-batch.satellite-loader-job threw a JobExecutionException:
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load an HTTP implementation from any provider in the chain. You must declare a dependency on an appropriate HTTP implementation or pass in an SdkHttpClient explicitly to the client builder.
at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:87) ~[!/:3.22.1]
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202) [!/:?]
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573) [!/:?]
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to load an HTTP implementation from any provider in the chain. You must declare a dependency on an appropriate HTTP implementation or pass in an SdkHttpClient explicitly to the client builder.
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:111) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.DefaultSdkHttpClientBuilder.lambda$buildWithDefaults$1(DefaultSdkHttpClientBuilder.java:49) ~[?:?]
at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:403) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.DefaultSdkHttpClientBuilder.buildWithDefaults(DefaultSdkHttpClientBuilder.java:43) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.lambda$resolveSyncHttpClient$7(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:357) ~[?:?]
at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.resolveSyncHttpClient(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:357) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.finalizeSyncConfiguration(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:296) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.syncClientConfiguration(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:185) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.sso.DefaultSsoClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultSsoClientBuilder.java:39) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.sso.DefaultSsoClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultSsoClientBuilder.java:28) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.build(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:151) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.sso.auth.SsoProfileCredentialsProviderFactory$SsoProfileCredentialsProvider.(SsoProfileCredentialsProviderFactory.java:101) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.sso.auth.SsoProfileCredentialsProviderFactory$SsoProfileCredentialsProvider.(SsoProfileCredentialsProviderFactory.java:88) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.sso.auth.SsoProfileCredentialsProviderFactory.create(SsoProfileCredentialsProviderFactory.java:68) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.internal.ProfileCredentialsUtils.ssoProfileCredentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsUtils.java:191) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.internal.ProfileCredentialsUtils.credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsUtils.java:120) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.internal.ProfileCredentialsUtils.credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsUtils.java:102) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider.lambda$createCredentialsProvider$1(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:169) ~[?:?]
at java.util.Optional.flatMap(Optional.java:289) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider.createCredentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:169) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider.handleProfileFileReload(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:135) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider.resolveCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:126) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.MetricUtils.measureDuration(MetricUtils.java:50) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.internal.authcontext.AwsCredentialsAuthorizationStrategy.resolveCredentials(AwsCredentialsAuthorizationStrategy.java:100) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.internal.authcontext.AwsCredentialsAuthorizationStrategy.addCredentialsToExecutionAttributes(AwsCredentialsAuthorizationStrategy.java:77) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.internal.AwsExecutionContextBuilder.invokeInterceptorsAndCreateExecutionContext(AwsExecutionContextBuilder.java:125) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.invokeInterceptorsAndCreateExecutionContext(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:69) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$0(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:64) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:179) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:62) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:52) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:63) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.getObject(DefaultS3Client.java:4482) ~[?:?]
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client.getObject(S3Client.java:7881) ~[?:?]

I am using karaf and maven in my application. I am doing successful  aws sso login by running command  "aws sso login --profile <PROFILE_NAME> before running my application. then running mvn install and then karaf command to run karaf.
I am getting below exception while trying to access s3 bucket.The same is working in other people's machine with this same aws profile login. I am using java 17. and software.amazon.sdk version is 2.20.99. I want to be able to access s3 bucket to read file and upload file by running my application locally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.